# C#: Selecting the Text of a Node using HTML Agility Pack and XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

having a problem with selecting the text contain within a particular node on HTML Page. I haven't used XPath before but using the HAP Explorer this was the path given for the text I wanted

```
        string xpath = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[4]/div[5]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/span[1]";
        //Using WatiN for Browser Control
        IE ie = new IE(url);
        ie.WaitForComplete();
        var html = new HtmlDocument();
        html.LoadHtml(ie.Html);
        //Test HTML Loads
        string test = html.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        HtmlNode node = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

Node always returns NULL.

Comment: I don't think this question can be properly answered without seeing the HTML of the page.

Comment: The problem is that the XPath expression you are using does not correspond (in some way or another) to the structure and/or node-names in the XML document, which you haven't shown. In order for anyone to be able to find the cause of the problem, it is necessary that you show the XML document against which the given XPath expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe some versions of IE XPath are 0 based... thus you would need to subtract 1 from each "array" index.